# How to install in Windows 10 an R package (MCMCpack) that is "not available"?

Tags: r, package, installation

I realize there are a bunch of questions along the same lines, but the permutations abound in the specifics, and I'm not sure there is a generic command to just fetch directly the package from wherever it is hosted from inside R.

The specific package in my case is [MCMCpack](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/MCMCpack/versions/1.4-6), and this is the error:

```
> install.packages("MCMCpack")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/anton/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘MCMCpack’ is not available (for R version 3.5.2)
```

Comment: update your R version to >= 3.6.3

Comment: ... as the package cran page states that it depends on R (≥ 3.6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to install it on my Mac, and same Error pops up.

If you use Rstudio you can download the package locally and install it manually by clicking on Packages -> Install -> Install from: Package Archive File.

You can find the download source on: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MCMCpack/index.html

It should then be possible to choose the downloaded MCMCpack package.